# Toggle transparency grid in Affinity Designer

Tags: transparency, affinity-designer

Is there a way to toggle the transparency grid on and off as you can in Illustrator (by hitting cmd + shift + d)?

Picture of transparency grid in Illustrator for reference:

[image: picture of transparency grid in Illustrator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is no way to quickly toggle between them, as you can read [here](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/80090-designer-quickly-toggle-transparency-grid/&tab=comments#comment-420950).

One can show the transparency grid the following way, but toggeling it off and on via shortcut is not yet possible:

In the File menu click "document setup"

[image: file menu with document setup highlighted]

And then under the "colour" tab check "transparent background"

[image: document setup dialogue with highlighted colour tab and transparent background checkbox]